# Looking for ideas to format one array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have one three dimensional array which is like below.

```
  Array
(
[d1] => Array
    (
        [c1] => Array
            (
                [t1] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 2
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 1
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 1
                    )

                [t2] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 0
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 0
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 0
                        [a7] => 1                            
                    )

                [t3] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 3
                        [a3] => 2
                        [a4] => 4
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 2
                        [a7] => 3                            
                    )
            )

        [c2] => Array
            (
                [t1] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 2
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 2
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 2                            
                    )

                [t2] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 0
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 0
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 0
                        [a6] => 0
                        [a7] => 0                           
                    )

                [t3] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 2                            
                    )
            )

    )
[d2] => Array
    (
        [c1] => Array
            (
                [t1] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 2
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 1
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 1
                    )

                [t2] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 0
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 0
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 0
                        [a7] => 1                            
                    )

                [t3] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 3
                        [a3] => 2
                        [a4] => 4
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 2
                        [a7] => 3                            
                    )
            )

        [c2] => Array
            (
                [t1] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 2
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 2
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 2                            
                    )

                [t2] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 0
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 0
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 0
                        [a6] => 0
                        [a7] => 0                           
                    )

                [t3] => Array
                    (
                        [a1] => 1
                        [a2] => 1
                        [a3] => 1
                        [a4] => 1
                        [a5] => 2
                        [a6] => 1
                        [a7] => 2                            
                    )
            )

    )

)
```

This is the PHP code for array:

```
$data = array(
  'd1' => array(
    'c1' => array(
      't1' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 1,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 1,
      ),
      't2' => array(
        'a1' => 0,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 0,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 0,
        'a7' => 1,
      ),
      't3' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 3,
        'a3' => 2,
        'a4' => 4,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 2,
        'a7' => 3,
      ),
    ),
    'c2' => array(
      't1' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 2,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 2,
      ),
      't2' => array(
        'a1' => 0,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 0,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 0,
        'a6' => 0,
        'a7' => 0,
      ),
      't3' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 2,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'd2' => array(
    'c1' => array(
      't1' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 1,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 1,
      ),
      't2' => array(
        'a1' => 0,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 0,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 0,
        'a7' => 1,
      ),
      't3' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 3,
        'a3' => 2,
        'a4' => 4,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 2,
        'a7' => 3,
      ),
    ),
    'c2' => array(
      't1' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 2,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 2,
      ),
      't2' => array(
        'a1' => 0,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 0,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 0,
        'a6' => 0,
        'a7' => 0,
      ),
      't3' => array(
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 1,
        'a4' => 1,
        'a5' => 2,
        'a6' => 1,
        'a7' => 2,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now i want to split this array into several arrays and put those arrays into one array like below.

```
   Array
(
[0] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t1
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 2
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 1
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 1
        )
[1] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t2
            [a1] => 0
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 0
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 0
            [a7] => 1
        )
[2] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t3
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 3
            [a3] => 2
            [a4] => 4
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 2
            [a7] => 3
        )
[3] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t1
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 2
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 2
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 2
        )
[4] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t2
            [a1] => 0
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 0
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 0
            [a6] => 0
            [a7] => 0
        )
[5] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t3
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 2
        )
[6] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d1
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t1
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 2
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 1
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 1
        )
[1] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d2
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t2
            [a1] => 0
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 0
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 0
            [a7] => 1
        )
[7] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d2
            [c1] => c1
            [t1] => t3
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 3
            [a3] => 2
            [a4] => 4
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 2
            [a7] => 3
        )
[8] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d2
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t1
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 2
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 2
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 2
        )
[9] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d2
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t2
            [a1] => 0
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 0
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 0
            [a6] => 0
            [a7] => 0
        )
[10] => Array 
        (
            [d1] => d2
            [c1] => c2
            [t1] => t3
            [a1] => 1
            [a2] => 1
            [a3] => 1
            [a4] => 1
            [a5] => 2
            [a6] => 1
            [a7] => 2
        )
)
```

Looking for any ideas how to proceed......

Comment: What exactly is the change you want to make? That's a big array of seemingly arbitrary data to me xD

Comment: What is your objective with doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? It takes ages to change a var_dump to a usable array (especially, this large).

Comment: Input array is three dimensional array....I want to break into small arrays......

Comment: My objective is i need to break this array into small arrays so i can render it easily in my view as for my comfort. If i don't it will be difficult for me in my view file...........

Comment: @SamuelCook I am not getting any ideas how to proceed. I am looking for idea.....

Comment: @SamuelCook, posted the PHP array for you. Have at it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$data` is your original multidimensional array:

```
$final = array();
foreach($data as $di => $dv){
    foreach($dv as $ci => $cv){
        foreach($cv as $ti => $tv){
            $final[] = array_merge(array("d" => $di, "c" => $ci, "t" => $ti), $tv);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($final);
```

You can see a demonstration [here](http://codepad.org/QLvegIQL)